# Как указать путь к внешнему файлу?

Tags: java, path

Программа "prog.jar" находится в папке в которую её скопировал пользователь. В этой же папке находится файл "data.sav" в который программа будет записывать и считывать данные. Как правильно прописать путь к файлу "data.sav" чтобы программа смогла найти этот файл. Я ведь заранее не знаю в какую папку пользователь поместит программу вместе с файлом. Т.е. нужен путь относительно самой программы.

Comment: Поидее `new File("")` даст ссылку на тек. каталог с программой

Comment: вот вам ссылка на варианты https://www.baeldung.com/java-current-directory

Comment: @Chubatiy, разве именно программы? :) Тут немного сложнее. Относительный путь идет относительно текущей активной директории, т.е. из папки, откуда был произведен запуск java. Но, если запуск был например из `C://`, а программа находилась на рабочем столе, то активной директорией будет `C://` и тогда `new File("")` вернет `C://`

Comment: Я попробовал первый вариант  new File("")  и он работает! Сам думал, что не будет работать. Т.к. внутри jar файла программа состоит из вложенных папок. Но оказалось, что программа в jar файле рассматривает себя как один файл. Попробовал переносить "prog.jar" и  "data.sav" в разные папки - всё работает. Спасибо за помощь